When re-entering the scene, writes "No Cameras rendering" in unity
When re-entering the scene, writes "No Cameras rendering". I have 2 scripts, which make the transition to another scene. There are cameras on all the scenes. Saves are not performed anywhere. When the first scene starts for the first time, it starts without any problems.
Scene one:
...
bool isFirst = true;
void Update{
...
   if(isFirst){
      SceneManager.LoadScene("two");
      isFirst = false;
   }
   ...
}
...

Scene two:
...
bool isFirst = true;
void Update{
...
   if(isFirst){
      SceneManager.LoadScene("one");
      isFirst = false;
   }
   ...
}
...

And after that, "No cameras rendering" is output.
It is necessary that the action takes place on the first scene, then after its execution, the second scene starts. And then, after completing the task, the second scene would start.
P. S. recently updated Unity Hub, maybe the problem is because of this. The unity version is 2022.3.17f, WebGL.

Well this means there is no active camera in your scene so nothing is rendered ... could you provide a bit more code context .. hard to tell what exactly you are trying to achieve and what exactly fails / misbehaves ...

Camera should be present in the scene, its GameObject should be active and Camera component enabled, otherwise this message is shown. Is it possible that some script is enabling/disabling your camera? Btw. Unity Hub has no impact on your project, you should not worry about it.

I realized that it's not about the script. I created a copy of the problematic scene and deleted this script from the scene, but the problem did not go away. Then I disabled all the objects in this scene except the camera, and there was no error. If anything, the camera was on in the first and second scenes.

I found the problem. the fact is that in the main player control script there was a page where there was a check for true. If false, the line of making the camera inactive was executed.
